# Header encoding issues with Mailkit and Mimekit

Tags: c#, mailkit, mimekit

When I use Mailkit to send emails, I noticed that it automatically decides to encode both the content as well as headers. Now, the content encoding is perfect however some email clients have difficulty decoding the headers which are like.

Is there a way to instruct the client to not encode certain headers?.
List-Unsubscribe: 
 =?us-ascii?q?=3Chttps=3A=2F=2Fbarlinkar=2Eus19=2Elist-manage=2Ecom=2Funsubscribe=3Fu=3D8c60690?=
 =?us-ascii?q?5a7e637766f218816b&id=3D2e47bac84d&e=3D407e758886&c=3De27229afde=3E=2C?=
 =?us-ascii?q?_=3Cmailto=3Aunsubscribe-mc=2Eus19=5F8c606905a7e637766f218816b=2Ee27229a?=
 =?us-ascii?q?fde-407e758886=40mailin=2Emcsv=2Enet=3Fsubject=3Dunsubscribe=3E?=
X-Report-Abuse: 
 =?us-ascii?q?=3Chttps=3A=2F=2Fmailchimp=2Ecom=2Fcontact=2Fabuse=2F=3Fu=3D8c606905a7e637766f218?=
 =?us-ascii?q?816b&id=3De27229afde&e=3D407e758886=3E?=
To: k****@****.***

EDIT: Jstedfast pointed out some errors and I fixed them but the overall result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt the problem is that the header value is encoded. Your value is invalid to begin with.

Here's the raw value that you are using:

```
https://barlinkar.us19.list-manage.com/unsubscribe?u=8c606905a7e637766f218816b&id=2e47bac84d&e=407e758886&c=e27229afde>, <mailto:unsubscribe-mc.us19_8c606905a7e637766f218816b.e27229afde-407e758886@mailin.mcsv.net?subject=unsubscribe>List - Unsubscribe - Post: List - Unsubscribe = One - Click
```

Do you see anything wrong with that?

First, each URL should be enclosed in `<>`'s. Your first URL is missing the leading `<` character.

Secondly, you are including the `List-Unsubscribe-Post` header in the value of the `List-Unsubscribe` header. They need to be 2 distinct headers.

In other words, the receiving client is probably getting confused as to what the value is supposed to be because it is completely borked.

Comment: I noticed the mistake and am fixing it.

Comment: Maybe, I have worded it incorrectly, is there a way to prevent encoding of a few headers using Mailkit, I tried using "Encoding.Ascii" and it seemed not to work.

Comment: No, there is no way to avoid encoding if MimeKit decides it needs to. It also shouldn’t matter. Don’t try to out-think MimeKit. 99% of the time you’ll be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance, am checking with a client who claimed that it was an issue with his email client.

Comment: @jstedfast: I have the same problem. If the header gets longer, MimeKit reformats it with `=?utf-8...` and then some email clients can't decode it. I checked a lot of messages I recieved, and they all have the `List-Unsubscribe` header not encoded.

Comment: Can you post an example in a new issue on https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit ?